# Debian KVM Server - Add Secondary Subnet

Tags: networking, debian, linux-networking, kvm-virtualization, bridge

I have a Debian 10 server (from Hetzner) that I want to set up as a KVM host to set up virtual machines for myself.

The server itself has a static IP like so:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface lo inet6 loopback

auto enp35s0
iface enp35s0 inet static
  address 95.217.122.234
  netmask 255.255.255.192
  gateway 95.217.122.193
  # route 95.217.122.192/26 via 95.217.122.193
  up route add -net 95.217.122.192 netmask 255.255.255.192 gw 95.217.122.193 dev enp35s0

iface enp35s0 inet6 static
  address 2a01:4f9:4a:37d5::2
  netmask 64
  gateway fe80::1
```

I'm not sure what these lines do and how they affect my situation:

```
# route 95.217.122.192/26 via 95.217.122.193
up route add -net 95.217.122.192 netmask 255.255.255.192 gw 95.217.122.193 dev enp35s0
```

I have been given a secondary subnet that has been "statically routed on the IP 95.217.122.234", that I intend to allocate to the guests. The details are:

- Subnet:  95.216.106.56
- CIDR: /29
- Netmask: 255.255.255.248
- Broadcast: 95.216.106.63

I have a guess that I would need to configure my interfaces file to be like so:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto enp35s0
iface enp35s0 inet manual

auto kvmbr0
iface kvmbr0 inet static
    address 95.216.106.56
    netmask 255.255.255.248
    network 95.216.106.56
    broadcast 95.216.106.63
    gateway 95.217.122.193
    bridge_ports enp35s0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_maxwait 0
```

However, I'm not sure this will "work" and even if it did, whether it would be wasting one or more IP addresses (e.g. my initial static IP at 95.217.122.234).

Perhaps it needs to be more like so:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface lo inet6 loopback


# Main Host IP
auto enp35s0
iface enp35s0 inet static
  address 95.217.122.234
  netmask 255.255.255.192
  gateway 95.217.122.193
  # route 95.217.122.192/26 via 95.217.122.193
  up route add -net 95.217.122.192 netmask 255.255.255.192 gw 95.217.122.193 dev enp35s0


# Secodary subnet
auto enp35s0:0
iface enp35s0:0 inet manual


# KVM Bridge
auto kvmbr0
iface kvmbr0 inet static
    address 95.216.106.56
    netmask 255.255.255.248
    network 95.216.106.56
    broadcast 95.216.106.63
    gateway 95.217.122.193
    bridge_ports enp35s0:0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_maxwait 0
```

What is the ideal way for me to set it up so that my KVM host uses the static IP that was initially assigned to it, but my KVM guests are directly accessible from the internet if I manually assign them IPs within the secondary subnet?

#### No Forwarding

I did see [this similar post](https://serverfault.com/questions/421151/kvm-with-one-host-ip-and-a-different-subnet-for-machines), but I would prefer it if there was no forwarding/masquerading being set up through the  host if possible. Ideally the guests are accessed directly on their IP even though they share the same physical connection as the host.

#### No DHCP

I've seen other posts that were complicated by DHCP being in place across two different subnets. In this case there is no DHCP and I am going to be manually assigning static IPs to all the guests myself.

Comment: You should state that you're using Hetzner services. This explains the strange additional route (which could be configured cleaner): https://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Netzkonfiguration_Debian/en#Main_IP_Address "In order to prevent the accidental use of a foreign IP address, our infrastructure rejects any Ethernet packets that are not addressed to the gateway address.". This is likely a PVLAN environment with validation from gateway: hairpinning to the LAN by the gateway.

Comment: This might perhaps be relevant: https://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Zusaetzliche_IP-Adressen/en#Subnets

Comment: I have added the fact that I am using hetzer to the post. I also made sure to read that post on subnets from hetzner before posting this question. I really just want to figure out what I need to post in my interfaces file to set everything up permanently and easily readable/understandable. The post has me confused as to whether this secondary subnet has to be routed "through" my main IP or not. Perhaps there are two ways to do this, and the way that doesn't route through forwarding the main IP makes two of the IPs unuseable?